# About the definition of convex optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the following problem:

$\mathop{\max}\limits_{x}\;\;f_0(x)\\
s.t.\;\;f_i(x)\le0,i=1,2,\cdots,m\\
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;h_j(x)=0,j=1,2,\cdots,n$

where $f_i(x),i=0,1,\cdots,m$ is convex function, and $h_j(x)$ is linear function. Then, whether this problem is a convex optimization problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a convex optimization problem.

The flaw is with the objective function where we are suppose to minimize a convex function.

Maximizing a convex function doesn't have properties such as local optimal is a global optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And cloud you please give me some references in which the standard definition of convex optimization is given?

Comment: See for example the book by boyd and Vandenberghe https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: I used Bersekas's Convex Analysis and Optimization and also Boyd.